# Merge PDFs while preserving hyperlinks

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf, phpdocx

I'm currently building a download function that will generate numerous PDFs, and then merge them all together.

However, the links on the Table of Contents page stop working once the PDFs are merged.. All of the links are functioning when the PDF is originally generated, but once it's merged they stop working.

I'm currently using DomPDF to generate the original PDFs, and then PHPdocx's MultiMerge class to combine them all.

I've tried using different libraries to merge the PDFs, but all of them have the same result.

Note: the site is built on Laravel 5.2.

So, my question is, is it possible to somehow merge PDFs using PHP while still preserving all hyperlinks ? Or even going in and editing the final PDF once it's generated to insert the links..

Any help or tips would be really appreciated.

Thanks !